# List(of T) not cooperating with For Each... Next Statement

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, foreach

I'm having trouble understanding exactly why this is happening.

(until I get the SQL rights from my employer) I'm developing a program that requres authentication, so I'm using an XML document, and reading it with the XDocument utility. Everything is loading into the collection of users properly. The collection is defined as this inside a class called 'UserDatabaseManager':

the collection:

```
Private UserCollection As New List(Of User)
```

the parent of UserCollection is defined as:

```
Public UserDatabaseController As New UserDatabaseManager()
```

Here's the User class:

```
Public Class User
    'CONSTANTS ----------------------------
    Public Enum RoleCode
        BasicQAAgent = 0
        QAAdministrator = 1
        ITadmin = 5
    End Enum

    'VARIABLES ----------------------------
    Dim uname As String = ""
    Dim fname As String = ""
    Dim pass As String = ""
    Dim userrole As RoleCode = 0
    Dim idnumber As Integer = 0
    Dim createDate As String = ""
    Shared Function SerializeUserFromXMLNode(ByVal XMLelement As XElement) As User
        With XMLelement
            Return New User(.@name, .<fullname>.Value, .<creationday>.Value, .<password>.Value, .<role>.Value)
        End With
    End Function

    Public Sub New(ByVal Name As String, ByVal FullName As String, ByVal CreationDay As String, ByVal PassHash As String, ByVal Role As RoleCode)
        fname = FullName : uname = Name : createDate = CreationDay : pass = PassHash : userrole = Role
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property UserName As String
        Get
            Return uname
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property FullName As String
        Get
            Return fname
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property UserRoleCode As RoleCode
        Get
            Return userrole
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property UserIDNumber As Integer
        Get
             Return idnumber
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property PasswordMD5Hash As String
        Get
            Return pass
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property CreationDate As Date
        Get
            Return createDate
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

I have my own user created. Breakpoints confirmed that *my user*, along with all the other records were successfully loaded from the XDocument. I can do:

```
UserCollection.Item(0)
```

and my user class will be returned (I know i'm index 0 in the xdocument).

***Now. What if I want to search for a user using another field?*** 
 
I have a function in the user database manager class (the parent class of the user collection, the user class, and the XDocument tool) that goes through the users, finds the user that matches the name, and returns an instance of the user back to the calling of the function:

```
Public Function GetUserByName(ByVal name As String) As User
    For Each usr As User In UserCollection
        If usr.UserName = name Then
            Return usr
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Nothing **ALWAYS** gets returned, in fact, a breakpoint on the "If usr.Username..." confirmed that ForEach statement isn't even running the loop!

So basically the end result is a *NullObjectReference* from the login screen. Here is the code that calls GetUserByName in the login screen form:

```
Private Sub Btn_login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_login.Click
    DisableLoginElements() 'custom sub
    'try login
    'Try
    Dim inputUsr As String = tbox_Username.Text : Dim inputPass As String = CalculateMD5FromString(tbox_Password.Text)
    tbox_Password.Clear()
    If mainMDI.UserDatabaseController.GetUserByName(inputUsr) IsNot Nothing Then 'HIGHTODO: FIX NULLOBJECTREF FROM USER SEARCH.
        'crosscheck the password provided calculates same MD5 hash as MD5 hash stored in DB. if not, throw MD5calculationVarianceEx Exception
        If mainMDI.UserDatabaseController.GetUserByName(inputUsr).PasswordMD5Hash = inputPass Then
            mainMDI.initializeMainMDIwithUser(mainMDI.UserDatabaseController.GetUserByName(inputUsr)) 'authentication success!
        Else
            Throw MD5calculationVarianceEx 'Password does not match
        End If
    Else
        Throw UserNotFoundEx 'user was not found 
    End If
    'Catch ex As Exception 'an error occured, determine error
    'MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Login Error: QA Commander")
    'EnableLoginElements()
    'End Try
End Sub
```

Where you see the HIGHTODO comment is where nothing is returned. I commented out the Try statement for debugging purposes.

**PLEASE HELP ME SEARCH IN A LIST(OF T) BY A PROPERTY WITHIN THE OBJECT THAT 'T' REPRESENTS!!**

Edit: Here are copies of the XML, and UserDatabaseManager in full:

User Database Manager:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports Microsoft

Public Class UserDatabaseManager

Public ReadOnly UserDatabaseManagerVersion As String = "1.0"

Private ReadOnly DBManager As Integer 'User ID Number of the database administrator
Private Company As String
Private Department As String

Private UserCollectionIndex As New Specialized.StringCollection
Public UserCollection As New List(Of User)

Dim xmlMgr As XDocument


Public Sub New(ByVal Optional databaseXMLPath As String = "")
    If Not databaseXMLPath = "" Then
        'Load datasheet from location
        xmlMgr = XDocument.Load(databaseXMLPath)
        If Not xmlMgr.<UserDB>.<version>.@value = UserDatabaseManagerVersion Then 'User Database is outdated.
            Throw UserDBfileVersionMismatchEX
        End If
        DBManager = xmlMgr.<UserDB>.<dbAdministrator>.@value
        Company = xmlMgr.<UserDB>.<company>.@value
        Department = xmlMgr.<UserDB>.<department>.@value
        Dim usersInDB As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xmlMgr.Descendants("user")
        For Each elm As XElement In usersInDB
            Dim foundName As String = elm.@name
            Dim userEntry As UserDatabaseManager.User = New User(elm.@name, elm.<fullname>.Value, elm.<creationdate>.Value,
                                                                 elm.<password>.Value, elm.<role>.Value)
            UserCollection.Add(User.SerializeUserFromXMLNode(elm))
        Next
    Else
        'create empty instance
    End If
    'get metadeta from XDocument

End Sub

Public Function GetUserByName(ByVal name As String) As User
    For Each usr As User In UserCollection
        If usr.UserName = name Then
            Return usr
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
Private Function GetUserByID(ByVal ID As Integer) As User
    For Each usr As User In UserCollection
        If usr.UserIDNumber = ID Then
            Return usr : Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
Public Class User
    'CONSTANTS ----------------------------
    Public Enum RoleCode
        BasicQAAgent = 0
        QAAdministrator = 1
        ITadmin = 5
    End Enum

    'VARIABLES ----------------------------
    Dim uname As String = ""
    Dim fname As String = ""
    Dim pass As String = ""
    Dim userrole As RoleCode = 0
    Dim idnumber As Integer = 0
    Dim createDate As String = ""
    Shared Function SerializeUserFromXMLNode(ByVal XMLelement As XElement) As User
        With XMLelement
            Return New User(.@name, .<fullname>.Value, .<creationday>.Value, .<password>.Value, .<role>.Value)
        End With
    End Function

    Public Sub New(ByVal Name As String, ByVal FullName As String, ByVal CreationDay As String, ByVal PassHash As String, ByVal Role As RoleCode)
        fname = FullName : uname = Name : createDate = CreationDay : pass = PassHash : userrole = Role
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property UserName As String
        Get
            Return uname
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property FullName As String
        Get
            Return fname
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property UserRoleCode As RoleCode
        Get
            Return userrole
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property UserIDNumber As Integer
        Get
            Return idnumber
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property PasswordMD5Hash As String
        Get
            Return pass
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property CreationDate As Date
        Get
            Return createDate
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Database XML:

```
<UserDB>
  <version value="1.0" />
  <lastEditedDate value="6/21/2018 3:23PM" />
  <dbAdministrator value="0000001" />
  <company value="Anomaly Squared" />
  <department value ="Quality Assurance" />

  <DBPreferences>
    <DefaultPassword>Password18</DefaultPassword>
    <DefaultPasswordHash>E527FABE14F0F6C0C7AD35886614BEAE</DefaultPasswordHash>
    <ForcePassChangeIfDefault>True</ForcePassChangeIfDefault>
  </DBPreferences>



  <QAAgents>
    <user name="mwendel">
      <userid>0000001</userid>
      <password>8814CD66C7804638B4CCE9233CBF4987</password>
      <fullname>Matthew Wendel</fullname>
      <role>5</role>
      <creationdate>6/23/2018</creationdate>
      <activityHistory>
        <action kind="selfCreatedAccount" date="6/23/2018" result="0x0" />
      </activityHistory>
    </user>

    <user name="jappleseed">
      <userid>0185432</userid>
      <password>E527FABE14F0F6C0C7AD35886614BEAE</password>
      <fullname>Johnny Appleseed</fullname>
      <role>1</role>
      <creationdate>6/23/2018</creationdate>
      <activityHistory>
        <result kind="ITCreatedAccount" date="6/23/2018" result="0x0" />
      </activityHistory>
    </user>
  </QAAgents>


</UserDB>
```

```
      User role Definitions
        0 = Basic QA Agent. 
          Ability to:
            • create new evaluations
            • view completed evaluations
            • add employees

        1 = QA Administrator
          Same as basic, but in addition:
            • add/create QA Agent accounts.
            • Can edit previous evaluations.
            • Produce evaluations of Basic QA Agents
            • add/edit/remove campaigns

        5 = IT/Systems Administrator
            Full atonomy to edit and maintain all elements of the system.
```

Comment: are you able to post your xml file?

Comment: also, can you post the properties of UserDatabaseManager too

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply! I made edits to the question with my code, and a link to PasteBin for the XML.

Comment: No worries, I'll check it out and see what I can do

Comment: The Get UserByname, is that going to be getting values from the database or windows authentication

Comment: GetUserByName() inquires the UserCollection List(of T) object within the UserDatabaseManager

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with the `UserDatabaseManager` class.  However, I strongly suggest that you enable Option Strict and fix the issues identified by the IDE.

Comment: `Private UserCollection As New List(Of User)` and `Public UserCollection As New List(Of User)` Which one is being filled the Public or the Private and then which one are you using in the For Each?

Comment: I really not familiar with this type of code but it seems that userEntry is a fully fleshed out User.  `Dim userEntry As UserDatabaseManager.User = New User(elm.@name, elm.<fullname>.Value, elm.<creationdate>.Value,
                                                                 elm.<password>.Value, elm.<role>.Value)`
            `UserCollection.Add(User.SerializeUserFromXMLNode(elm))` I want it to be `UserCollection.Add(userEntry)`. userEntry doesn't seem to be used elsewhere. Sorry if I am way off base.

Comment: Mary: To try and combat not being able to find the users in the List(Of User), when users were initialized I would insert a friendly name into the string collection UserCollectionIndex at the same index location as that user in the UserCollection list, to make it easier to find. It is not implemented and UserCollectionIndex (Specialized.StringCollection) can be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. I actually can answer my own question!!!!

So the GetUserByName function, when it was being called, was referring to the List(Of User) that was in the default instance of the UserDatabaseManager, INSTEAD of the one I declared as UserDatabaseController! 
 
Using the keyword **Me** is *VERY* important, as it makes sure that the function points to the instance of the object that you declared, NOT it's default empty collection. Here is the updated function, and everything worked as is:

```
Public Function GetUserByName(ByVal u_name As String) As User
    For Each usr As User In Me.UserCollection
        If usr.UserName = u_name Then
            Return usr
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

the Me identifier in "... User in Me.UserCollection.." basically fixed this. Thanks to everyone for their help!